# Escaping multiple different characters in a String

Tags: java

I want to escape different characters (`#, $, %, &, \, ^, _, {, }, ~`) in a given Java String with a backslash (`#` becomes `\#`, `$` becomes `\$` and so on).

Is it possible to archieve this without calling the `String#replace` or `String#replaceAll` method multiple times on the string?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Can't you find a strategy for doing that? Using a loop for example?

Comment: Why would you want to call `String#replaceAll` multiple times? It uses regex so you can find each of special character and replace it with ``\`` followed by what was found.

Comment: @Pshemo can you explain a little bit more how to do that?

Comment: Take a look at Harald's answer. He posted code representing what I meant. In short we can use `$x` notation in replacement part to represent match from group `x`. Since group 0 represents entire match we can write `$0` to use what regex found.

Comment: @Pshemo thank you for your explanation. That was just what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression

```
String escaped = s.replaceAll("[" + Pattern.quote("#$%&\\^_{}~") + "]",
    Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\")+"$0")
```

Comment: That was just what I was looking for. Thank you